# retrieve data from firebase failed

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

for some reason, after I retrieve data from firebase, the data did retrieve successfully.

```swift
    func retrieveData(user: User) {
        //let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let email = user.emailAddress!
        // print(email)
        databaseRef?.child("userTable").child(email).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            print("whats up ")
            if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:String] {
                let res = value["posts"]
                user.deserialize(data: res!)
                if( user === self.u1) {
                    print("they are same obj") // this will print, so they are pointing to the same address
                }
                print(self.u1.posts) // this also printed the things I want
            }
            // ...
        })
        if( user === self.u1) {
            print("they are same obj outside") // this also prints
        }
        print(self.u1.posts) // but once they exist closure, this one just become empty, as as user.posts
    }
```

I really don't understand what is happening here. It seems like data just is stored properly after closure. Also, i dont know why the code outside closure prints first. Thanks so much for any helps!

This is the running result

they are same obj outside
[:]

whats up 
they are same obj
["a@hotmail 0": RadiUs.Post]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to asynchronous operations, there is no value (yet) at your third print statement.

Your first two print statement actually execute after your third print statement even if it doesn't look like it. If you create breakpoints at each print statement, you will be able to see the order of execution.

So to guarantee the data is back from Firebase, you should only be calling the data inside here:

```
databaseRef?.child("userTable").child(email).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Manipulate data here
        }
```

If you prefer the calls to be synchronous, you can do the following:

```
    func retrieveData(user: User) {
    //let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let email = user.emailAddress!
    // print(email)
    databaseRef?.child("userTable").child(email).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        print("whats up ")
        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:String] {
            let res = value["posts"]
            user.deserialize(data: res!)
            if( user === self.u1) {
                print("they are same obj") // this will print, so they are pointing to the same address
            }
            print(self.u1.posts) // this also printed the things I want
        }
        // ...
    })
    if( user === self.u1) {
        print("they are same obj outside") // this also prints
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        print(self.u1.posts) // Now called sequentially 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks sfung3, I added break points for each print statement, but they just skipped break points inside closure. I don't know why. At the same time, is there anyway to make this execute in sequential?

Comment: However, if I run it(not adding break points), it does print out things inside closure

Comment: I updated the original answer. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: i updated. but it is still the same issue... any other helps?